# Typescript: Valid contravariant generic typing is actually invalid

Tags: generics, types, typescript

The following code is perfectly valid typescript:

```
interface Promise<T> {
    then(resolved: (p: T) => number): number;
}

function as4(): Promise<{ x: number, y: number }> {
    let r: Promise<{ x: number }> = {
        then: resolved => resolved({ x: 4 })
    };
    return r;
}

function addAs4(): number {
    return as4().then(p => p.x + p.y);
}
```

Similar code is pretty common when working with asynchronous promises.

However, the resulting javascript code is actually broken, because the property `p.y` does not exist and thus the addition results in a `NaN`.

As far as I understand it now, typescript allows covariant assigning of generic types to allow for code like

```
let common: Array<{ x: number }> = [];
let special: Array<{ x: number, y: number }> = [];

common = special;
```

So I figure, because the type parameter `T` in `Promise<T>` only occurs in an argument position it switches to allow contravariant assigning. However, the `T` does not actually occur as a parameter to `then` but as a parameter to an parameter, so I would expect it to switch back to covariant assigning (meaning that `resolved` can only be called with a more special type than `{ x: number }`. At least in my example this seems to make sense. Is there a good reason why it doesn't?

Also, this behavior takes away a lot of type safety when working with promises a lot. Is there a way to somehow tell the typescript compiler to treat generic types as invariant (I think in flow you can do such a thing)? Or maybe another solution to detect these kind of bugs?